# Timeout when using select() webdriver selenium function Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code to select option from a drop down menu

```
def select_option(driver, locator, text):
    try:
        select_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((locator)),f"Option with '{text}' timeout."
        )
        select = Select(select_element)
        select.select_by_visible_text(text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        raise Exception(f"Option with '{text}' does not exist in the select element.")

while(True):
    select_option(driver, (By.ID, 'OrgId'), venue)
    time.sleep(1)
```

and the error that i received is
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Desktop\foler\main.py", line 66, in <module> select = Select(select_element) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Thats is so weird coz if it is my select_element throw timeout error then i should receive the error f"Option with '{text}' timeout.", i dont know why it shown error on Select(select_element) when the select_element is actually located what should i do?

I want to know what should I suppose to handle this case.

Comment: Can you change `EC.visibility_of_element_located` to `EC.element_to_be_clickable` and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `except` clause only catches `NoSuchElementException`.
If you want it to also get executed for the exception shown in the error message you posted, it also needs to catch `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`.

You can do something like:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
...
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        raise Exception(f"Option with '{text}' does not exist in the select element.")
...
```

Ideally it should be handled by another except clause, with a more descriptive error message regarding timeouts:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
...
    except NoSuchElementException:
        raise Exception(f"Option with '{text}' does not exist in the select element.")
    except TimeoutException:
        raise Exception("Timeout waiting for element to be located.")
...
```

Comment: Hi Paolo I actually wanna know the reason of Timeout.

Comment: To provide a working solution we would need more information about the web page you are targeting. I would try making sure the content of your `select_element` is exactly the one you want; and then I would play around with methods other than `select_by_visible_text`, some are listed here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms.